# Infinite Loop while inputting the different data type values in STACK

Tags: c++, algorithm, stack

Below is the code for STACK with no overflow since I am using vector concept. Program seems to be working fine as long as I push **integers**, but as soon as I push **float value** (for testing) the output screen goes to infinite loop and debugger doesn't even stop at **cin** statement and it simply crosses it without giving the control to the console window.

```
#include"iostream"
class Mystack
{
private:
    int *input;
    int top;
    int capacity;
public:
    Mystack();
    ~Mystack();
    void push(int x);
    int pop();
    int topElement() const;
    bool isEmpty() const;
    void print();
};
Mystack::Mystack()
{
    top = -1;
    capacity = 5;
    input = new int[capacity];
}
Mystack::~Mystack()
{
    delete[]input;
}
void Mystack::push(int x)
{
    if (top + 1 == capacity)
    {
        int *vec = new int[capacity+capacity];
        for (int i = 0; i <=top; i++)
        {
            vec[i] = input[i];
        }
        input = vec;
        capacity = capacity * 2;
        top++;
        input[top] = x;
    }
    else
    {
        top++;
        input[top] = x;
    }
}
int Mystack::pop()
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("Stack Underflow");
    }
    else
    { 
        std::cout << "The popped element is" << input[top];
        return input[top--];

    }
}
bool Mystack::isEmpty() const
{
    if (top == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Is Empty" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Not Empty" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
}
int Mystack::topElement() const
{
    if (top == -1)
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("No Element to Display");
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "The top element is : " << input[top];
        return input[top];
    }
}
void Mystack::print()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= top; i++)
    {
        std::cout << input[i] << " ";
    }
}
int main()
{
    Mystack s1;
    int num, ch = 1;
    while (ch >0)
    {
        std::cout << "\n1. PUSH" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "2. TOP" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "3. IsEmpty" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "4. POP" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "5. EXIT" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "6. Print" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Enter the choice" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> ch;  // DEBUGGER DOES NOT GIVE CONTROL TO CONSOLE WINDOW AND ASK FOR INPUT ONCE I PUT FLOAT VALUES, IT SIMPLE CROSSES IT
        switch (ch)
        {
        case 1:
            std::cout << "Enter the number to be pushed" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> num;
            s1.push(num);
            break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << "Get the TOP Element" << std::endl;
            try
            {
                s1.topElement();
            }
            catch (std::out_of_range &oor)
            {
                std::cerr << "Out of Range error:" << oor.what() << std::endl;
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            std::cout << "Check Empty" << std::endl;
            s1.isEmpty();
            break;
        case 4:
            std::cout << "POP the element" << std::endl;
            try
            {
                    s1.pop();
            }
            catch (const std::out_of_range &oor)
            {
                std::cerr << "Out of Range error: " << oor.what() << '\n';
            }
            break;
        case 5: exit(0);
        case 6:
            s1.print();
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Enter a valid input";
            break;
        }
    }
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that you are trying to read an `int` from standard input *without checking whether the reading actually succeeded*, so it just keeps retrying over and over.  Since `ch` is only an integer, `cin` refuses to read anything that doesn't look like an integer.  (Also, your stack holds `int`s.  How would it ever accept `float`s?)

Comment: You're inputting an `int`. When you type e.g. `3.14` that would read the `3` and leave the `.14` in the input buffer. At this point I think you already have an input conversion error, and an input stream in **error mode** just ignores further operation attempts.

Comment: I gave valid input to **ch** i,e, **int**, I gave invalid value i.e, float value while pushing. And once I did that the infinite loop started and it didn't even stop at **cin** to ask for further values.

Comment: Like @Rufflewind said, you can't expect your program to work for `float`s when you declare all your variables as `int`s. Consider using a [template class](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/) instead.

Comment: Actually its the first time I encountered a situation where debugger simply ignored **cin**. I will use template class. Thanks! And why the negative vote :/

Comment: Side note: with `input = vec`, you are triggering a memory leak, so you may want to `delete[] input` beforehand.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to avoid that memory leak.

Comment: Do you also understand **why** it yields a memory leak?

Comment: @barakmanos Honestly, I think as I am already going to assign all the values again in the next code section so I should probably get rid of the values that are already there. I think I am totally wrong. So yes I don't understand memory leak thing. :(

Comment: In the constructor, you are setting the member variable `input` to point to a dynamically allocated memory segment. In function `push`, you are setting it to point to another dynamically allocated memory segment. So at this point, you no longer have anything pointing to that first memory segment, hence you have no way to de-allocate it (hence it will remain allocated "forever").

Comment: @barakmanos Ya I got your point. Do I need to use **delete []vec** also, once the copying is done. Because everytime capacity reaches its limit, a new memory will get allocated? Am I making sense?

Comment: You are making sense in the fact that I can understand how you're thinking (and why you are wrong). You initially set variable `vec` to point a dynamically allocated memory segment, and then you set variable `input` to the value of variable `vec`. So at that point (after you set `input = vec`), both variables have the same value, right? This means that both variables are pointing to the same (dynamically allocated) memory segment. If you delete that memory segment, then both variables will be pointing to a memory segment which you are no longer allowed to use.

Comment: So - no, you **should not** `delete[] vec`. Your misunderstanding probably stems from the fact that you think that with `delete[] x` you are deallocating the variable `x`, which is wrong. What you are really doing, is to dealocate the memory segment **pointed to** by variable `x`.

Comment: I totally understood your point. So once I use **delete []vec**.The memory which is now holding the old elements and also going to hold the next new elements, gets deleted. That is obviously something we don't want. As a matter of fact we need that memory to keep the old elements intact and for storing the elements to come in future. Many Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you input the **int** value for example as **1.1 (invalid int value)**. Input conversion error occurs and the input stream  because of invalid data ignores the rest of the operation even the **cin**.  Make your code more generic in order for it to handle **float or double or char**.